# How to copy/paste text without formatting by default?

Tags: text, clipboard

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and I find it annoying that by default the copy/paste functionality also pastes the text format. Most of the time when I copy/paste text I only want to paste the ascii text without any formatting. Is there a way to configure that behavior?

Comment: Again a feature designed without UX. I am willing to bet style copying is useful to less than 5% of the users in less than 20% of cases. This should have never made it up to the default feature!

Comment: should be the other way around: right click "paste with formatting" for the rare cases when you want format as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [parcellite](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parcellite) [image: Install parcellite]. It keeps a history of the clipboard.

Comment: I tried Parcellite and it seems to almost do what I want. The thing is that the Parcellite history saves the information in text only but the First copy I do stills contains the formatting. So I need to copy a string and before to paste it I have to click the Parcellite panel icon, then click the text I just copied, then I can paste it in text only.

Comment: I accepted this as "accepted answer" since there was nothing better. And it is A LOT faster than pasting to gedit first and then in my document.

Comment: @jmbouffard "since there was nothing better" Now there is, see the answer of teehoo, since using Parcellite.It sounds overcomplicated…

Comment: CTRL-SHIF-V will do it without having to install anything...

Comment: Parcellite *does* copy the style.

Comment: @MaxL. not if you use atlassian products...

Answer (score 48):

In fairly recent Ubuntus you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to paste plain text.

Comment: Anyone know if there's a way to make this the default behaviour?

Comment: Seams not to work whit kubuntu.

Comment: Works great on my Ubuntu 14.04 - what a relief to find such an easy solution!

Comment: Works on Manjaro though

Comment: how to swap the behaviours of Ctrl-Shift-V and Ctrl-V ?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. (On ubuntu 21.10)

Answer (score 4):

I've found a way to achieve this after some searching online and experimenting with my environment.

You can create a custom shell script which you can then bind to a key shortcut in your desktop environment. I'm using Xfce on Linux Mint (which is based on Ubuntu). Xfce allows me to override Ctrl-C by simply defining that as the shortcut in Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts, but I prefer using a different shortcut, Ctrl-Alt-C, so that I'm still able to copy with formatting in the rare cases I need to.

Here's how I did it.

Install xclip:

```
apt-get -y install xclip
```

I don't know about other desktop environments, but Xfce didn't like me using a pipe in the custom keyboard command, so I had to make a script with the xclip-line, which is then bound to my keyboard shortcut (Ctrl-Alt-C).

My personal habit is putting custom commands in `~/.bin` and then adding that directory to the PATH variable.

Here's how you do that, if so inclined:

```
mkdir ~/.bin
echo 'export PATH=~/.bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

(Note that you will need to re-initialize your session for that change to take effect, meaning you'll have to log out of your desktop environment and back in again. See if it worked by typing `echo $PATH` in a terminal after having logged in again.)

I've then created the script `~/.bin/copy-without-formatting` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
xclip -o | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Remember to make it executable with the following line:

`chmod +x ~/.bin/copy-without-formatting`

Then, since I'm using Xfce, I've gone to Settings -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts and added a shortcut with the *full path* to the script, without variables or a tilde. So if my username were `mrgaga`, the string would be `/home/mrgaga/.bin/copy-without-formatting`. Then I've configured the shortcut.

Xfce activates the changes immediately when I've closed the window so you should be able to check if it works right away, without logging out and in again, at least if your environment is similar enough to mine.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm in Xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do it automatically. A workaround of course is to paste it into [gedit](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gedit) [image: Install gedit] and copy it from there.

Comment: I've been using this workaround for a while but now I'd like to find a real solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Another way (likely not secure) is to use your URL bar as a deformat tool. Most of the time it is easier to get to than launching another application.

Comment: I don't usually down vote since I find this counter productive, but definitely this is **not** a solution. At the best an awful workaround.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger I agree this this only a workaround, but to say that it is not a solution implies that it doesn't work. Does it not work? Let me know if there is something broken.

Comment: You are correct, apologies because you received my anger toward this wrongly designed feature and your solution, though painful is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In some places where, for some weird reason ([looking at you Atlassian](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-28229)), `ctrl+shift+v` doesn't work, one could use this tool: [CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) and then add a global shortcut to it, that overrides the paste without formatting behavior of Ubuntu (which sometimes might be forced to work in another way)

Answer (score -2):

In my Ubuntu 20.04 focal (x86-64) Cinnamon 4.8.6 you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste text without formatting.